# IPython %save magic error

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to save a python file that I loaded into my IPython notebook with the `%loadpy` magic. When I try and save the file with `%save settings.py` I get the following error:

```
File `settings.py` exists. Use `%save -f 'settings.py' -f` to force overwrite
```

Then when I use `%save -f 'settings.py' -f` I get the error:

```
'-f' was not found in history, as a file, url, nor in the user namespace.
```

`%save -f 'settings.py'` yeilds the error `'' was not found in history, as a file, url, nor in the user namespace.` as well.

Any idea how to correctly save a `.py` file so that it overwrites the previous version? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [13]: %save -f settings.py 1-10 # saves lines 1 to 10 to settings.py
In [14]: %save? # Gives you the help on the save command


Usage:
  %save [options] filename n1-n2 n3-n4 ... n5 .. n6 ...
```

n1-n2, n3-n4 are ranges of lines that you want to save. n5, n6 are individual line numbers that you want to save.  Add `-f` option to force save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to reference it to the cell it's being executed in? I ask because I'm trying to make a tutorial and locking `%save` to a particular line will save the wrong code if cells are executed out of order / or cells before it are executed multiple times.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to do that.

Comment: Since I posted the question, I've been looking through the documentation and source code, and haven't found anything to do that. Thats actually what I wanted to do so I'll ask a new question so its more clear what I'm looking for. Thanks for your answer, (+1).

Comment: The help message is not explicit enough about the second argument being mandatory, not optional (it seems), which feels unnatural and opposed to the principle of least astonishment (PoLA)